# Creating 3D tables in Powerpoint

Tags: powerpoint, presentation, powerpoint-2010, powerpoint-2013, powerpoint-2007

I am trying to make a 3D table in Powerpoint with a gradient effect that look somewhat like the image shown below but unable to make it. None of the default designs/styles look like the one I displayed below. I could not find a matching gradient effect in the **Fill and Line** option. When I select the table and go to **format shapes** and select **Effects**, everything is greyed out under **3-D format**.

How can I get this desired effect in Powerpoint?

[image]

Comment: Please ask only programming questions here - you can ask software usage questions on _Super User_.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a 3D effect, it's just a gradient fill

1. Select all the cells of the table
2. Go to `Format Shape`
3. Under "Fill", check "Gradient fill"
4. Edit the gradient to taste

[image]

Comment: I have already played with the gradient effect but could not get the colors to match. Can you tell me Gradient stop settings, hex or rgb code of the color and with transparency and brightness percentage? I am looking for an exact match of the sample. Meanwhile I will also try once again.

Comment: There are programs that allow you to pick up the RGB value of any screen pixel. You could use one of them to get at least the starting/ending colors of the gradients in your sample. Pixie by Nattyware is a nice free one.  http://www.nattyware.com/pixie.php